# How to call out multiple image from server into auto created new webpage using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a question regarding auto create webpage from HTML template,

1. How to auto create new webpage from HTML template and call out multiple image from server in the auto created webpage?

Please see below for my coding, Thank You.

below is the PHP code for auto create webpage,

```css
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE loginUser='$loginUser'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$data['multiple'] = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data['multiple'][] = $row['multiPic'];
    }

$tpl_file = "Service.html";
$tpl_path = "../folder/";
$members_path = "../folder/multiPicFolder/";

$data['username'] = $username; 

$placeholders = array("{multiple}", "{username}");

$tpl = file_get_contents($tpl_path.$tpl_file);

$new_member_file = str_replace($placeholders, $data, $tpl);

$html_file_name = $data['username'].".html";

$fp = fopen($members_path.$html_file_name, "w+"); 
fwrite($fp, $new_member_file); 
fclose($fp);

$_SESSION['html_file_name'] = $html_file_name;

?>
```

below is the HTML template for auto create,

```html
    <?php
        session_start();
        include 'databasehander.php';
    ?>

      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html>
      <body>

        <?php 

            foreach({multiple} as $eachPic) {
              if (!empty($eachPic)) {
                  echo "<img src="../$eachPic">";
              } 
            }

        ?>

        <?php include '../footer.php';?>

      </body>
```

Comment: the way you have it wont work. You are trying to pass an array into that foreach, but what you are really doing  with fwrite is writing out a string. To make it work you need to write out the entire array as a string in the file.. though the way you are tasking it seems ver chaotic. What is your end goal?

Comment: my guess is there is no need for `if (!empty($eachPic))` inside `foreach`

Comment: @addie, thanks for reply. My purpose is auto create a Service Detail page for each service when user signup his service. how to write the entire array? are you mean I need to save the entire array as a string in a field of MySQL? Is it possible call a php function in this auto created HTML page? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution I found,

```css
<?php 

$tpl_file = "Service.html";
$tpl_path = "../folder/";
$members_path = "../folder/multiPicFolder/";

$data['multiple']="";  
    foreach($_SESSION['multiple'] as $ServiceCat1)  
    {  
        $data['multiple'] .= $ServiceCat1.",";  
    }  

$data['username'] = $username; 

$placeholders = array("{multiple}", "{username}");

$tpl = file_get_contents($tpl_path.$tpl_file);

$new_member_file = str_replace($placeholders, $data, $tpl);

$html_file_name = $data['username'].".html";

$fp = fopen($members_path.$html_file_name, "w+"); 
fwrite($fp, $new_member_file); 
fclose($fp);

$_SESSION['html_file_name'] = $html_file_name;

?>
```

```html
<?php
        session_start();
        include 'databasehander.php';
    ?>

      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html>
      <body>

        <?php 

            $getMultiplePart1 = '{multiple}';
            $findMultiplePart1 = explode(",", $getMultiplePart1);

            $multiplePart1="";  
            foreach($findMultiplePart1 as $multipleA) { 
                    $multiplePart1 .= "../".$multipleA.",";  
            }  
            
            $getMultiplePart2 = $multiplePart1;
            $findMultiplePart2 = explode(",", $getMultiplePart2);
            
            foreach($findMultiplePart2 as $multipleB) {  
                    echo "<img src='".$multipleB."'>";
            }

        ?>

        <?php include '../footer.php';?>

      </body>
```